# Running Continumm Standalone

Tags: java, apache, console, localhost, continuum

I have downloaded apache continuum.

After that i unpacked and i typed continuun console.

It´s started fine... but when i put localhost:8080/continuum in the browser the console show this error: What´s happend?

```
jvm 1    | org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invo
king javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(Defau
ltErrorHandler.java:92)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDisp
atcher.java:378)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDisp
atcher.java:119)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Jsr199JavaCompiler.compile(Jsr199J
avaCompiler.java:208)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.ja
va:384)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453
)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilatio
nContext.java:625)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServle
tWrapper.java:374)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServle
t.java:492)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:
378)
jvm 1    |      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.
java:648)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHand
ler.java:455)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedH
andler.java:137)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHan
dler.java:577)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(Sess
ionHandler.java:231)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(Cont
extHandler.java:1072)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandl
er.java:382)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(Sessi
onHandler.java:193)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(Conte
xtHandler.java:1006)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedH
andler.java:135)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:2
76)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:1
03)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet
.java:566)
jvm 1    |      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
jvm 1    |      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.
java:648)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter
(ServletHandler.java:1336)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter.d
oFilter(StrutsExecuteFilter.java:85)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter
(ServletHandler.java:1307)
jvm 1    |      at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent
(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
jvm 1    |      at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(Site
MeshFilter.java:77)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter
(ServletHandler.java:1307)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter.d
oFilter(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:82)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter
(ServletHandler.java:1307)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilt
erInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(
OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter
(ServletHandler.java:1307)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHand
ler.java:453)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedH
andler.java:137)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHan
dler.java:559)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(Sess
ionHandler.java:231)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(Cont
extHandler.java:1072)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandl
er.java:382)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(Sessi
onHandler.java:193)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(Conte
xtHandler.java:1006)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedH
andler.java:135)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.han
dle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(Han
dlerCollection.java:154)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(Handle
rWrapper.java:116)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest
(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplet
e(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandle
r.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:6
35)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.j
ava:235)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttp
Connection.java:82)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectC
hannelEndPoint.java:627)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectCh
annelEndPoint.java:51)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedT
hreadPool.java:608)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedTh
readPool.java:543)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    | 2013-05-27 23:52:11.265:WARN:oejs.ErrorPageErrorHandler:EXCEPTION
jvm 1    | org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invo
king javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(Defau
ltErrorHandler.java:92)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDisp
atcher.java:378)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDisp
atcher.java:119)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Jsr199JavaCompiler.compile(Jsr199J
avaCompiler.java:208)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.ja
va:384)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453
)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilatio
nContext.java:625)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServle
tWrapper.java:374)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServle
t.java:492)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:
378)
jvm 1    |      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.
java:648)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHand
ler.java:455)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedH
andler.java:137)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHan
dler.java:577)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(Sess
ionHandler.java:231)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(Cont
extHandler.java:1072)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandl
er.java:382)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(Sessi
onHandler.java:193)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(Conte
xtHandler.java:1006)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedH
andler.java:135)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:2
76)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.error(Dispatcher.java:112
)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler.handle(ErrorP
ageErrorHandler.java:136)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:348
)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHand
ler.java:538)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedH
andler.java:137)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHan
dler.java:559)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(Sess
ionHandler.java:231)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(Cont
extHandler.java:1072)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandl
er.java:382)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(Sessi
onHandler.java:193)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(Conte
xtHandler.java:1006)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedH
andler.java:135)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.han
dle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(Han
dlerCollection.java:154)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(Handle
rWrapper.java:116)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest
(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplet
e(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandle
r.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:6
35)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.j
ava:235)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttp
Connection.java:82)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectC
hannelEndPoint.java:627)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectCh
annelEndPoint.java:51)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedT
hreadPool.java:608)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedTh
readPool.java:543)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed a JDK, make sure javac is in the PATH somewhere before attempting to start Continuum.